# showing gradle error when I run in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.3].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4 mins 22.387 secs
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE

I get this error when I build on jenkins on my windows machine. So how could I accept the license and fix the above issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the new `sdkmanager` to update your SDK? You just have to run it once on the machine in question to accept the license for a given version.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html#usage

You can also use the GUI which comes alongside this tool. See the following question for more information:

https://superuser.com/questions/1161536/android-bat-brings-up-sdk-manager-gui-why-is-sdkmanager-bat-needed